# What does this error mean: is not a valid l-value?

Tags: verilog

This is the Verilog code, and I have this error (o is not a valid l-value). Could someone help me?

```
module ts ;
    reg[3:0] in1,in2;
    wire[3:0] o;
    integer i,j;

    Sommatore4Bit s(.in1(in1), .in2(in2), .out(o));
    
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
        $dumpvars(1);
        for (i = 0 ; i < 16; i = i+1 ) begin
            for (j = 0; j < 16 ; j = j+1) begin
                in1 = i;
                in2 = j;
                o = in1 + in2;
                display;
            end
        end
    end
    task display;
        $display(" in1 -> %d , in2 -> %d, out %d",in1,in2,o);
    endtask
endmodule

module Sommatore4Bit (
    input[3:0] in1, input[3:0] in2, output reg[3:0] out
);
    always @(in1 or in2) begin
        out = in1 + in2;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the `o` signal as a `wire`, and this means you can not make an assignment to it in the `initial` block.

When you delete this line, the error goes away:

```
            o = in1 + in2;
```